# Angular - @Input always pick's up undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have app component (where is my menu, and my button), and I have my home component (in which I want to change something based on is menu shown or not).

I have boolean that is basically state of the menu true for that it is shown, and false if it hidden.

What I see in the console:

When I try to read values with @Input, firstly it returns true or false (as it should) and immediately after that the value is changed to undefined. I tried this with ngDoCheck command.

Here is my code:

home.component.ts

```js
 @Input() state: any; // tried boolean too, but kept any just in case

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    console.log(this.state)
  }
```

app.component.html

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img
    [@arrow]="menuState"
    (click)="menuToggle()"
    class="icon-img"
    src="../../assets/icons/arrow.svg"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
</div>
<app-home [state]="isMenuShown" [message]="message"></app-home>
```

Also, I tried to pass random message, just to see is this about booleans, same happens...

Comment: Can you make a StackBlitz project for this?

Comment: the actual type of the input doesn't REALLY matter in the way you think it does. This code seems to imply that `isMenuShown` is turning to undefined... so we'd need to see the code relevant to that variable.

Comment: Only thing that is happening to isMenuShown is that when toggle function is called it is changed to false and vice versa, i don't see how it can become undefined?

Comment: you may be doing something unintended by mistake.  Need to see a repro or the relevant code to be sure.

Comment: https://github.com/velibor7/my-first-time-with-angular/tree/menu-setup

Comment: Also, by looking at the console (ng-reflect-state class) I can see that the value is either hide or show, as it should be (i'm trying both booleans and string, just to be sure), until the @ Input picks it up, so the problem must occur after @ Input picks it @bryan60

Comment: don't use a getter to define your variable being used in an animation.  Looks like the animation is doing something to break it.  just use a normal variable.

Comment: Just tried that, nothing changed, I think it has nothing to do with animation since I'm trying to send "message" which doesn't change anywhere, but the message becomes undefined too

Comment: I cleared cache, if thats important

Comment: @V.Velibor is there any reason why you're looking at the value in ngDoCheck (and not another lifecycle method)? What do you intend to do with the value?

Comment: @V.Velibor the div that is surrounding <app-home> in your code has *ngIf="isMenuShown()", which will always be true because that function returns a string of "show" or "hide". Can you change isMenuShown() in the *ngIf to isMenuShownVar and try again?